# how to Read/Write multiple objects from file in C++?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

When i try this writing multiple objects to file is done properly.
but while i try to Read multiple objects from file it show only data of last object.

Write Multiple objects to file:-

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{

    s[i].getdata();

    ofstream file("Simple.txt");

    if(file.is_open())
    {
        cout<<"File created"<<endl; 
        file.write((char*)&s[i],sizeof(s[i]));
        file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"File not Open../"<<endl;
    }

}
```

where, s is object 
       used  in for loop as generating multiple objects.

Comment: well, you open and close the file each time your loops executes. You probably want to open the file before your loop and **not** close it, since `std::ofstream`'s destructor will do that for you (unless you want to explicitely reopen a file with the very same object)

Comment: Hey welcome to stackoverflow, you may want to visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to get some tips on how to perfect your questions that will help us help you :)

Comment: Note that naively sending the bytes of an object to a file in C++ won't work in most cases, for all the same reasons that naively sending the bytes of an object across the network won't work:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485870/why-serialization-when-a-class-object-in-memory-is-already-binary-c-c

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `ofstream file("Simple.txt");` you are opening a file in write mode.
And that you are doing for every iteration.
It means every time you write a file it is writing from beginning. ie, you are overwriting your file everytime.
You should try opening in append mode.
That might help.

Also as the first comment suggested, it is not a good idea to open and close a file in every iteration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
std::ofstream file;

file.open("Simple.txt" | std::ofstream::app);
...
```

You have to open the file in append mode.

You could also declare the file handle before the loop, and then just read in the values, then after the loop close the file handle.